# Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 281, col 0 from CursorWindow with Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I am getting this exception with my DAO in Room, at what seems random moments:

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException
Couldn't read row 281, col 0 from CursorWindow. Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString (CursorWindow.java)
android.database.CursorWindow.getString (CursorWindow.java:460)
android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString (AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
com.myapp.android.model.db.PlacesDao_Impl$6.call (PlacesDao_Impl.java:734)
io.soulpicks.android.model.db.PlacesDao_Impl$6.call (PlacesDao_Impl.java:693)
android.arch.persistence.room.RxRoom$4.apply (RxRoom.java:111)
android.arch.persistence.room.RxRoom$4.apply (RxRoom.java:108)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.tryOnNext (FlowableMap.java:124)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$ObserveOnConditionalSubscriber.runAsync (FlowableObserveOn.java:637)
io.reactivex.internal.operators.flowable.FlowableObserveOn$BaseObserveOnSubscriber.run (FlowableObserveOn.java:176)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Saw it reported by Crashlytics multiple times on multiple devices, but I haven't encountered the bug myself.

This is my PlaceDao class:

```
@Dao
interface PlacesDao {

    @Query("select * from Places where placeId = :id")
    fun getPlace(id: String): Flowable<Place>

    @Query("select * from Places where placeId in (:placesIds) order by distance, placeName ASC")
    fun getPlaces(placesIds: List<String>): Flowable<List<Place>>

    @Query("select * from Places join list_results where Places.placeId = list_results.id order by distance, placeName ASC")
    fun getFilteredPlaces(): Flowable<List<Place>>

    @Query("select * from Places where placeId = :id")
    fun forId(id: String) : Place

    @Query("select * from Places where placeId in (:placesIds)")
    fun forIds(placesIds: List<String>): List<Place>


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun savePlaces(places: List<Place>)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun savePlace(place: Place)

    @Query("DELETE from Places")
    fun deleteAll()


    @Query("select * from Places")
    fun getAll(): Single<List<Place>>


    @Query("select * from Places where (experienceId IS NOT NULL) AND (experienceId != '') order by placeName")
    fun getMyPlaces(): Flowable<List<Place>>


    @Query("update Places set distance = :distance where placeId = :id")
    fun updateDistance(id: String, distance: Float)
}
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to debug it even, let alone fixing the issue!

Comment: Any chance you have figure it out this issue? Cause I'm having the similar one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem too. It is because of high volume of data. Room is not intended to store high volume data (pictures etc.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31653825)